# Error al querer poblar ModalPopupExtender con datos de GridView

Tags: ajax, asp.net, popup

Estoy tratando de editar los datos de una fila de un `GridView` los cuales, se llenan desde una base de datos en `Access`, Apenas estoy comenzando a usar `Ajax` y `Asp.Net`.

Este es el botón con el que mando a llamar al `panel`:

```
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="fa fa-reply" ForeColor="Blue" class="btn btn-info"
                         ID="Btn_edit" runat="server" Text="&nbsp Edit" CommandName="Edit" 
                           OnClick="Btn_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Este es mi codigo del `Panel`:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_edit_dummy" runat="server" style="display:none" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender
        ID="ModalExt1"
        runat="server"
        TargetControlID="Btn_edit_dummy"
        PopupControlID="PanelEdit"
        RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll"
        DropShadow="true"
        PopupDragHandleControlID="panelEditTitle">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelEdit" runat="server" CssClass="panel panel-primary" Width="750px" style="display:none">>
        <asp:Panel ID="panelEditTitle" runat="server" CssClass="panel-heading">
            <h3 align="center"><span><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp Re-Assign Tool</i></span></h3>
        </asp:Panel>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div align="center">
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-9" style="visibility: hidden">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">id</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_id" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Status" AutoComplete="off" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_id" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Wrong id"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce5" runat="server" TargetControlID="rfv5" ></ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Responsable</span>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="Txt_resp" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_resp" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You miss a responsable"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce6" runat="server" TargetControlID="rfv5" ></ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Tool</span>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="Txt_tool" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true" />
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_tool" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You miss the tool"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce7" runat="server" TargetControlID="rfv5" ></ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    &nbsp

                     /*********** mas `div's` ***********/

               <div class="panel-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="DismissBT" runat="server" Text="Dismiss" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" />
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitBT" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="edit" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </asp:Panel>
```

y no se como mandar a llamar los datos con codigo... espero alguien me pueda ayudar, he estado googleando pero no he conseguido encontrar uno que me quede claro, ya que usan sql, e imagines como bonotes y cambian la manera de usar el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Lo  podido solucionar...

Este es el `FrontEnd:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender
        ID="ModalExt1"
        runat="server"
        TargetControlID="hid"
        PopupControlID="PanelEdit"
        RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll"
        DropShadow="true"
        PopupDragHandleControlID="panelEditTitle">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelEdit" runat="server" CssClass="panel panel-primary" Width="750px" style="display:none">
        <asp:Panel ID="panelEditTitle" runat="server" CssClass="panel-heading">
            <h3 align="center"><span><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp Re-Assign Tool</i></span></h3>
        </asp:Panel>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div align="center">
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-9"  style="display:none">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">id</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_id" runat="server" class="form-control"  AutoComplete="off" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                &nbsp
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Responsable</span>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="Txt_resp" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_resp" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You miss a responsable"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Tool</span>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="Txt_tool" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true" />
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_tool" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You miss the tool"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Status</span>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Dpo_status" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Enabled="False">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Dpo_status" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select a status"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Nota</span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_notas" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_notas" Display="None" ErrorMessage="You need to assign a note"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    &nbsp
                            <div class="input-group col-xs-9">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Date</span>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_dates" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Txt_dates" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select the current date"  ValidationGroup="edit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    &nbsp
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="DismissBT" runat="server" Text="Dismiss" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" />
                <asp:Button ID="SubmitBT" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" ValidationGroup="edit" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Y este es el `BackEnd` para poblar el panel con la informacion del `GridView`:

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;

            Label Lbl_id = (Label)gr.FindControl("Lbl_id");
            Txt_id.Text = Lbl_id.Text;

            Label Lbl_resp = (Label)gr.FindControl("Lbl_resp");
            Txt_resp.Text = Lbl_resp.Text;

            Label Lbl_tool = (Label)gr.FindControl("Lbl_tool");
            Txt_tool.Text = Lbl_tool.Text;

            ModalExt1.Show();
        }
```